CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions works only on the first first population of the underlying ObservableCollection
I have a Grid with a CollectionViewSource set as follows:
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PriceHistoryItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding PriceHistory}" 
      IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Inserted" Direction="Descending"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
        <s:String>Inserted</s:String>
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource HistoryGrid}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PriceHistoryItemsViewSource}}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           ///...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>

In the ViewModel, the PriceHistory is an ObservableCollection updated by RefreshPriceHistoryAsync as follows:
public class OptionPriceHistoryViewModel : PriceHistoryViewModel
{
    //... other code
    public ObservableCollection<OptionPriceHistoryRecordViewModel> PriceHistory { get; } = new();

    public override async Task RefreshPriceHistoryAsync(string correlationId)
    {
        var priceHistory = await _historyProvider.GetOptionPriceHistoryAsync(id);
        PriceHistory.Clear();
        foreach (var priceHistoryRecord in priceHistory)
            PriceHistory.Add(new OptionPriceHistoryRecordViewModel(
                priceHistoryRecord.InsertDate,
                priceHistoryRecord.Username
                //... etc.
                ));
        
    }
}

This ViewModel is used as DataContext in a Window control.
The same window can be reused to show PriceHistory of various entities.
The sorting only works the first time the PriceHistory is populated. If the same Window is reused to show the history of various entities, the sorting is ignored on all calls after the first one (i.e. the items are displayed in the order they came in from DB).
How can I preserve the sorting when reusing the window?
Frankly, I don't understand why it's not working, because each time when the window is reused, a new instance of OptionPriceHistoryViewModel is created... and the binding of the items works but not their sorting.

Does this answer your question? CollectionViewSource sorting only the first time it is bound to a source

For me it works fine.
Are you sure that the property Inserted exists? Is it not InsertDate? What is his type?

The CollectionViewSource only updates itself when you modify the underlying collection. It does not reapply sorting and filtering. You would have to
a) use ICollectionView to sort and filter
b) or explicitly refresh the CollectionViewSource
c) or replace the collection instance (not recommended)
d) or raise the PropertyChanged event for the collection source property (not recommended)
public override async Task RefreshPriceHistoryAsync(string correlationId)
{
  var priceHistory = await _historyProvider.GetOptionPriceHistoryAsync(id);
  PriceHistory.Clear();
  foreach (var priceHistoryRecord in priceHistory)
  {
    PriceHistory.Add(new OptionPriceHistoryRecordViewModel(
      priceHistoryRecord.InsertDate,
      priceHistoryRecord.Username
      //... etc.
    ));        
  }

  ICollectionView priceHistoryView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.PriceHistory);
  priceHistoryView.Refresh();
}

